# Why do WebSockets use ("ws" and "wss") instead of ("http" and "https")?

Tags: websocket, url-scheme

What was the reason for registering special URI schemes: `ws` and `wss`?
I briefly read the specs, and didn't find any reason about this change.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.1

The WebSocket client sends special headers (`Connection: Upgrade`, `Upgrade: websocket`) which lets you relatively easily decide whether this is a normal HTTP request (`GET`,`POST` ...etc) or this is a WebSocket connection request.

Why can't WebSockets work using `http` and `https` schemes?

Comment: Because it isn't HTTP?

Comment: But it can use same host same port at the same time

Comment: @gre_gor - technically it connects using HTTP(S) before changing protocol. The question does make sense... even though it ignored future changes  to the handshake (such as ALPN).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't on the board or anything, but here's any 2¢...:

The protocol's handshake currently uses HTTP(S) for connection establishment, but this is as far as the HTTP involvement goes.

It's highly possible that future versions might extend the handshake possibilities, using technologies such as ALPN.

By using the URI scheme `ws://...` and `wss://...`, the handshake is decoupled from the URI, allowing future changes to occur with less disturbance.

Answer (score 0):

They use it for sake of architectural clarity, looks like there is no technical limitation why you could not handle your websocket connections using purely `http`.

Please notice javascript client libraries for handling websocket connections like [Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/), are handling websockets purely over http protocol, and even fail if you are explicitly providing host prefixed with `ws` protocol instead - A piece of simple example from showcase code:

> ```
> // Create a client instance
> client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(
>     location.hostname, Number(location.port), "clientId"
> );
> ```